# Flutter standard packages

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

As I see several dart packages published at [dart package website](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages), I am curious to know what packages does flutter endorse?

The question would be vague, so I would like to focus on a specific package [dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio). I have contacted few flutter developers, and have been told that the package is not yet a industry standard, also I was introduced to some packages that were published just hours back, for example [jaguar_retrofit](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_retrofit). I also see dart https package used frequently in flutter documentation.

This weighs me to look at what would be the most promising in the future. 
Can someone solve the package mystery for me, any flutter insights available?

Comment: There is no specific status of "endorsed by flutter team" for external packages. The Flutter team maintains [flutter/plugins](https://github.com/flutter/plugins) and [flutter/packages](https://github.com/flutter/packages) and can address issues with these packages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid question, but not one that you'll probably find a final answer to on stackoverflow (and it *may* be closed as off-topic although I won't cast that vote). You might find better luck at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ although there may not be too many dart/flutter specific people there; I don't know for sure.

But realistically, no-one knows what might happen to the packages in the future other than the people maintaining them. That would probably be a good first step - make contact with the developers as they will be able to give you a better indication of how committed to maintaining their code they are.

Other than that, what I'd look for is who the publisher of the package is (see below, under the "Author").

[image]

If it is the 'Dart Team' or 'Flutter Team', there's a fairly good chance it will be maintained. If it isn't, but the uploader has a '@google.com' email address, there's a chance it's just one of their 20% projects, but there's still a better chance of it being maintained than a random dev.

And finally, if the package's licence allows for it (which pretty much everything on pub should) you may be able to help the developer with it in the future, in which case everyone wins =).

Comment: Thanks @rmtmckenzie. I understand your point. I stumbled upon [this] (https://github.com/flutter/plugins) which have list of plugins that might be what flutter endorses, and this seems to be a limited resource page. Checking with the maintainers make sense !

Answer (score 0):

It helps to look at the official documentation:

- [Fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/)
- [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.io/json/)

More in the [cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/).

Some time ago, I took a look at the dio source code and I'm not really convinced that it is a good option. Basically it is just a thin wrapper around the standard http library.

The retrofit clone seems to rely on a custom JSON serializer code generator, instead of using one of the standard solutions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views on dio and retrofit. It helps!